# how can i solve this problem 'JSX element type does not have any construct or call signatures.' warning?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

[image]

i want to make item list to component using with fetched data(items).

what do is mean?, and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please paste your code not picture.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you made ItemComponent as a string, not an actual JSX Component.
You should make `ItemComponent.jsx` file make and actual component and try to render it again.